# Scrapy program is not scraping all data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am writing a program in scrapy to scrape following page, https://www.trollandtoad.com/magic-the-gathering/aether-revolt/10066, and it is only scraping the first line of data and not the rest.  I think it has something to do with my for loop but when I change the loop to be broader it outputs too much data, as in it output each line of data multiple times.

```
 def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        saved_name = ""
        for game in response.css("div.row.mt-1.list-view"):
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get() or saved_name
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            yield item
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('div.card > div.row'):
            item = GameItem()
            item["Card_Name"]  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get()
            for buying_option in game.css('div.buying-options-table div.row:not(:first-child)'):
                item["Condition"] = game.css("div.col-3.text-center.p-1::text").get()
                item["Price"] = game.css("div.col-2.text-center.p-1::text").get()
            yield item
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You didn't clarify about your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need below CSS (later you can use it as a base to process `buying-options` container):

```
 def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('div.card > div.row'):
            item = GameItem()
            Card_Name  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get()
            item["Card_Name"] = Card_Name.strip()
            for buying_option in game.css('div.buying-options-table div.row:not(:first-child)'):
                # process buying-option
                # may be you need to move GameItem() initialization inside this loop

            yield item
```

As you can see I moved `item = GameItem()` inside a loop. Also there is no need in `saved_game` here.

Comment: Well it no longer giving me unnecessary data its just giving me the card names I need.  But the loop for the pricing data is not working.  Even if there are multiple sellers each with different prices that specific card is only outputted once instead of 4 or 5 or however many different sellers there are and it is not giving me any prices for price.  It is instead grabbing data from the header line and just outputting 'quantity' for each price.  I have updated my answer with the new code and a partial snapshot of my current output.

Comment: I see now that in my hurry to try and get the program to work I forgot to change game to buying_option in second loop.  Now the program works fine.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`response.css("div.row.mt-1.list-view")` returns only 1 selector, so the code in your loop runs only once. Try this: `for game in response.css(".mt-1.list-view .card-text"):` and you will get a list of selectors to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

You're code -- it does not work because you are creating the GameItem() outside of your list loop. I must have missed a postcard about this .get() and .getall() methods. Maybe someone can comment how its different from extract?

**Your failing code**

```
 def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem() # this line right here only creates 1 game item per page
        saved_name = ""
        for game in response.css("div.row.mt-1.list-view"): # this line fails since it gets all the items on the page. This is a wrapper wrapping all the items inside of it. See below code for corrected selector.
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card-text::text").get() or saved_name
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            yield item
```

**Fixed code to solve your problem:**

```
 def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css("div.product-col"):
            item = GameItem()
            item["Card_Name"] = game.css("a.card-text::text").get()
            if not item["Card_Name"]:
                continue # this will skip to the next item if there is no card name, if there is a card name it will continue to yield the item. Another way of doing this would be to return nothing. Just "return". You only do this if you DO NOT want code after executed. If you want the code after to execute then use yeid.
            yield item
```